# Class template implementation with multiple vectors

Tags: c++, class, templates, vector

I'm creating a program that reads in a data file into a vector and then shows the minimum and maximum information for the vector. I also have to use a class template for finding the minimum and maximum. I'm wondering if there is a way I can reference ANY vector without having to specifically label the two vectors I want to use. In my code below, I have to state vector v1 to get my template to do the minimum and maximum. Is it possible to make this template for any vector?

```
    //Nicholas Stafford
//COP2535.0M1 
//Read in text file into multiple vectors and display maximum and minimum integers/strings.

#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>


using namespace std;

//Template code area
template <class T>
T min(vector<T> v1)
{
    T lowest = v1[0];
    for (int k = 1; k < 10; k++)
    {
        if (v1[k] < lowest)
            lowest = v1[k];
    }
    return lowest;
}

template <class T>
T max(vector<T> v1)
{
    T highest = v1[0];
    for (int k = 1; k < 10; k++)
    {
        if (v1[k] > highest)
            highest = v1[k];
    }
    return highest;
}


int main() {
    //Number of items in the file
    const int size = 10;
    //Vector and file stream declaration
    ifstream inFile;
    string j; //String for words in data file


    vector<int> v1(size); //Vector for integers
    vector<string> v2(size); //Vector for strings

    //Open data file
    inFile.open("minmax.txt");

    //Loop to place values into vector
    if (inFile)
    {

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                inFile >> v1[i];
                v1.push_back(v1[i]); //Add element to vector
            }

            cout << "The minimum number in the vector is " << min(v1) << endl;
            cout << "The maximum number in the vector is " << max(v1) << endl;




    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The file could not be opened." << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tryed to print out your v1 vector? The result may surprise you. Can you explain better what you mean by "Is it possible to make this template for any vector?" ? Do you want a single function that calculate all the maxima at the same time?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood something. Have you tried passing v2 to your template functions? Or changing the `v1` in your template definition/implementation to `v` and observing it still accepts `v1` as an argument?

Comment: Okay I found the error. When I used v1 it did the max and min just fine, but I didn't want to make two more templates just for another vector, kind of defeats the purpose of a template.

Comment: Always something small. When everything was in a reference to just v it worked. Just had an extra v1 lying around that I missed when I switched back to v. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're having a simple misunderstanding. Just because the function parameter to your `min` and `max` is `v1` doesn't mean the only thing you can call it with is something called `v1`. Actually, it will be a local copy of the vector passed in, locally named `v1`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
size_t sizeit(std::vector<T> v)  // try changing to v1, v2 and vx
{
    return v.size();  // change to match
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v1 { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::vector<float> v2 { 1., 2., 3. };

    std::cout << "v1 size = " << sizeit(v1) << "\n";

    std::cout << "v2 size = " << sizeit(v2) << "\n";
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/cK13bR

Comment: `v.size()` would help OP's max and min functions too.

Comment: What does knowing the size accomplish in reference to min and max?

Comment: @NStafford your templated functions work only for 10 sized vectors. If you use v.size() they will work for every size. And check the size of your v1 vector too...

Comment: Ah, that takes care of my problem with having to do define a size for my loops. I see now, thank you!